# Ошибка при получении user_id и nickname. Telegram, Aiogram, MySQL, Python

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создаю бота и вот в чем проблема: все username и user_id успешно заносятся в БД, но двумя отдельными строками. Как исправить и сделать их в одну?

[image: как выглядит в бд]

Код добавления в бд:

```
from aiogram.types import ChatActions
import asyncio
import logging
import keyboards as kb
import obsh_files
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from config import TOKEN
import sqlite3

logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s [ LINE:%(lineno)+3s ]#%(levelname)+8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

conn = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_id INTEGER, username TEXT)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

class SQLither:

    def __init__(self, database) -> object:
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def exists_user(self, user_id):
        """Проверка существования пользователя в БД"""
        return bool(self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,)).fetchone())

    def add_to_db(self, user_id, username):
        """Добавление пользователя в БД"""
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES(?)", (user_id,)) and self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('username') VALUES(?)", (username,))
        self.conn.commit()

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = SQLither("db.db")



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_hi1_command(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    if not db.exists_user(user_id):
        db.add_to_db(user_id, username)
    await message.answer("Привет!", reply_markup=kb.markup1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы записываете айди пользователя, а потом совсем отдельно username. Заносите данные через один execute.

```
self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id, username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id, username))
```

Comment: Как делать это правильно? Записывать одновременно и айди и юзернейм

Comment: Да. В крайнем случае можно заносить айди пользователя, а потом делать UPDATE по айди и уже добавлять остальные данные, но так делать не очень хорошо)

Answer (score 0):

1. изменить `self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES(?)", (user_id,)) and self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users ('username') VALUES(?)", (username,))` на `self.c.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id, username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id, username))`